# Converting Latitude Longitude Coordinates to Image Map Coordinates

Tags: c#, javascript, coordinates, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems

I'm almost positive this has been answered already; however, unable to find it since XY coordinates are overloaded due to their relative definition.

What I am trying to find/figure out is how to take latitude/longitude coordinates (e.g. 12.121212, -12.323232) and convert such so they can be mapped onto a 2-dimensional plane such as a point on an image map.

Has anyone solved this issue and know of a script or another SO question that they can point me to?

Ideally I'm seeking a solution in either JavaScript or .Net; however, can convert algorithms just the same.

Comment: First you need to pick a map projection: http://xkcd.com/977/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Somewhat related, but going the opposite direction: 
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080521142713AAnlVtI

Also filled with information: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This operation is called "projection."  You need to know the identity of the coordinate system you want to project into.  There is a lot of arcane lore here.

See this.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11560/convert-latitude-and-longitude-into-northings-and-eastings